# Using Almofireimage to download and then cache cell image

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am currently using [Alamofireimage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) to download images, and my goal is to cache them after they are done. Since the images are static, once they are downloaded, they would not need to be downloaded again.

Alamofireimage documentation says that, when using the simple `UIImageView` extension with `af_setImage`, the image is automatically cached. My goal is (and I couldn't find in documentation) is how I could access this cache, and then cache this permanently to the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the document here line 175
https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/blob/master/Source/UIImageView%2BAlamofireImage.swift

This method `af_setImage` will automatically find and load the image if you have it cached.
In this page, you can look at line 280 to manually access the cache.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for pointing out the source that allows this and line number!